# docker container couldn't locate file but file is present

Tags: docker

I am trying to package [gotty](https://github.com/yudai/gotty/releases) into a Docker container but found a weird behavior.

```
$ tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                
.
├── Dockerfile
├── gotty
└── gotty_linux_amd64.tar.gz
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.11.3

RUN mkdir -p /home/gotty
WORKDIR /home/gotty
COPY gotty /home/gotty
RUN chmod +x /home/gotty/gotty
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

The image was built without issue:

```
[strip...]
Removing intermediate container 0dee1ab645e0
 ---> b5c6957d36e1
Step 7/9 : COPY gotty /home/gotty
 ---> fb1a1adec04a
Step 8/9 : RUN chmod +x /home/gotty/gotty
 ---> Running in 90031140da40
Removing intermediate container 90031140da40
 ---> 609e1a5453f7
Step 9/9 : CMD ["/bin/sh"]
 ---> Running in 30ce65cd4339
Removing intermediate container 30ce65cd4339
 ---> 099bc22ee6c0
Successfully built 099bc22ee6c0
```

The `chmod` changed the file mode successfully. So `/home/gotty/gotty` is present.

```
$ docker run -itd 099bc22ee6c0
9b219a6ef670b9576274a7b82a1b2cd813303c6ea5280e17a23a917ce809c5fa
$ docker exec -it 9b219a6ef670 /bin/sh
/home/gotty # ls
gotty
/home/gotty # ./gotty
/bin/sh: ./gotty: not found
```

Go into the container, the gotty command is there. I ran it with relative path. Why the `not found`?

Comment: Instead of `ls` you should `ls -l` to see the attributes. The x attribute should be present, as long as you ran the new image. Maybe it’s the binary itself which returns the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into one of the more notorious problems with Alpine: Musl, instead of glibc. Check out the output of `ldd gotty`. Try adding `libc6-compat`:

```
apk add libc6-compat
```

and see if that fixes it.